# Android change typeface of entire application

Tags: android

In my android app I want to change the typeface of all text.I know how to change the typeface of textview ,button ,spinner etc using asset.But I want to change the typeface of entire application in a simple method??any help will be appreciable

Comment: Well sorry to tell you. There is no such thing. Except if you create your own view class.

Comment: not possible with simple method..you need to apply it to all of your views..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

two way to implement typeface:

**1)you have to create your own view class of textview or button.**

**2)you can use commonmethod :**

```
//use Singleton Design Pattern for better performance
public class CommonMethod{
  public static Typeface getFontTypeface()
    {
        Typeface mTypeface = null;
        if(mTypeface == null)
        {
            mTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(),"Helvetica_.ttf");
        }
        return mTypeface;
    }
public static void SetTypeface(Activity activity, TextView... edt) {

        for (int i = 0; i < edt.length; i++) {
            edt[i].setTypeface(getFontTypeface());
        }
    }
}
```

and set this function in all your activity like this:

```
CommonMethod.SetTypeface(getActivity(), txtfragedit, txtYoutube,
                txtFacebook, txtTwitter);
```

I hope its useful.

if your application is complete then 2nd method is preferable.and if  you start to build your app now then 1st method is preferable.

Answer (score -1):

Follow below nentioned steps :-

1) Get your fonts inside asset folder and create one string inside your strings.xml for the respective font like :

```
<string name="type_face_regular">AvenirLTCom-Light.ttf</string>
```

2) Create one class Let's call it as Utility.java.

3) Inside it write a method like below : -

```
public Typeface getFontTypeface()
{
    Typeface mTypeface = null;
    if(mTypeface == null)
    {
        mTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "font/" + mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.type_face_regular));
    }
    return mTypeface;
}
```

4) Use the above method through out your application to set font.